# d3 data update CSV - can't figure out how to update table cells

Tags: d3.js, html-table, insert-update, import-from-csv

I've got a haproxy status endpoint which outputs the following data:

[image]

I want to parse it's output and build a nice interactive dashboard (in this case monitoring which Riak nodes are up or down at a given time.

I've written the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>dadsa</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="viz"></div>
 <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
 <script>
 var hosts = [];
 var url = "http://localhost:8666/haproxy-csv";
 function update() {
     d3.csv(url, function(data) {
     hosts = data.filter(
             function(d){
                 console.log(JSON.stringify(  d) );
                 console.log(Object.keys(d));
                 console.log(d["# pxname"]);
                 return d["# pxname"] == "riak_backend_http"
                         && d["svname"] != "BACKEND";
             }
     ).map(function(d){
         return {"label": d["svname"],"value": d["status"]};
     });
     d3.select("#viz")
             .append("table")
             .style("border-collapse", "collapse")
             .style("border", "2px black solid")
             .selectAll("tr")
             .data(hosts)
             .enter().append("tr")
             .selectAll("td")
             .data(function(d){
                 return [
                     d["label"], d["value"]
                 ];
             })
             .enter().append("td")
             .style("border", "1px black solid")
             .style("padding", "5px")
             .on("mouseover", function(){d3.select(this).style("background-color", "aliceblue")})
             .on("mouseout", function(){d3.select(this).style("background-color", "white")})
             .text(function(d){return d;})
             .style("font-size", "12px");
 });
 }
 update();
 setInterval(update, 1000);
 </script>
 <button onclick="alert(JSON.stringify(hosts[0]))"> see value </button>
 <div id="svg"/>
 </body>
 </html>
```

That code works well, with one small flaw.. It continuously appends a new table element on each update. I've rewritten this code many times but whatever I write seems to just update once.

Here's what the output currently looks like:

[image]

I'm really ignorant about d3 so not even sure what exactly I should be binding or hooking into.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a new table with each update because you are actually appending a new table each time when you do this inside the update function.

```
...
d3.select("#viz")
   .append("table")
...
```

Instead create your table beforehand either through HTML tags or using javascript. Create it outside the update function. Say it's something like:

```
var myTable = d3.select("#viz")
               .append("table")
               .style("border-collapse", "collapse")
               .style("border", "2px black solid");
```

Now that you have your table set up we can update it using the 'D3.js way' of enter(), exit() and update() as follows:

```
//bind the data to rows
var rows = myTable.selectAll("tr").data(hosts); 
//append as needed using enter()
rows.enter().append("tr");
//remove placeholders in exit
rows.exit().remove(); 

//bind the data to columns in each row
var columns = myTable.selectAll("tr")
                     .selectAll("td")
                     .data(function(d){
                       return [
                         d["label"], d["value"]
                       ];
                     });

//enter and exit as above
columns.enter().append("td");
columns.exit().remove();

//finally update the columns
myTable.selectAll("td")
         .style("border", "1px black solid")
         .style("padding", "5px")
         .on("mouseover", function(){d3.select(this).style("background-color", "aliceblue")})
         .on("mouseout", function(){d3.select(this).style("background-color", "white")})
         .text(function(d){return d;})
         .style("font-size", "12px");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, that helped beautifully. I was temporarily flumoxed by the scoping behavior (coming from a couple of years of Erlang/Functional programming).

Answer (score 0):

Why not remove the table element on each update.
Add this line

```
d3.csv(url, function(data) {
   d3.select("#viz").select("table").remove();//removes the table
   //other code as usual
```